# Random color function for multiple paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html

So this is function to color 5 paragraphs randomly into one color.

```
#js
function color(){

    bgColorCode = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 100000);

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('#'+arguments[i]).style.backgroundColor = 
bgColorCode;
    }
}

#html
<button onclick = "color('p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5')">Color Paragraphs</button><br>
    <p id ="p1">
       random text
    </p>
    <p id = "p2">
       random text
    </p>
...
```

My question is now how to color 5 paragraphs randomly into diffrent color with only one button function?

Comment: just add the bgColorCode random code inside your for loop

Comment: Thanks its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gugateider suggests in his comment you can add the random color selection to your for loop, this way a new color will be generated for each graph:

```
function color(){

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
       bgColorCode = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 100000);
       document.querySelector('#'+arguments[i]).style.backgroundColor = bgColorCode;
    }
}

#html
<button onclick = "color('p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5')">
   Color paragraphs 
</button><br>
<p id ="p1">
   random text
</p>
<p id = "p2">
   random text
</p>
```